# Unconfirmed Transaction new

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

can someone help me with this?
thank you
https://blockchain.info/tx-index/1b8e3e8064d28e6728212169f1479c1b359a88452854844afa562de1e6d6d800

Answer (score 0):

Only wait for confirmations, the transfer is fine.

Here you can see that have 0/6 confirmations at this time: https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/1b8e3e8064d28e6728212169f1479c1b359a88452854844afa562de1e6d6d800/